# How we can limit the usages of VCores during Spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

I am writing a Spark structured streaming application in which data processed with Spark, needs be sink'ed to s3 bucket.

This is my development environment.

Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.16.1

Spark version 2.3.0.cloudera4

I want to limit the usages of VCores

As of now I have used spark2-submit to specify option as --conf spark.cores.max=4. However after submitting job I observed that job occupied maximum available VCores from cluster(my cluster has 12 VCores)

Next job is not getting started because of unavailability of VCores.

**Which is the best way to limit the usages of VCores per job?**

As of now I am doing some workaround as : I created Resource Pool in cluster and assigned some resource as

Min Resources : 4 Virtual Cores and 8 GB memory

Used these pool to assign a spark job to limit the usages of VCores.

```
e.g. spark2-submit --class org.apache.spark.SparkProgram.rt_app --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --queue rt_pool_r1 /usr/local/abc/rt_app_2.11-1.0.jar
```

I want to limit the usages of VCores without any workaround.

I also tried with

```
spark2-shell --num-executors 1 --executor-cores 1 --jars /tmp/elasticsearch-hadoop-7.1.1.jar
```

and below is observation.
[image]

Comment: Are you running on local mode or Mesos?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "--executor-cores" option it will assign the number of core to each of your executor.
can refer [1](https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/distribution_of_executors_cores_and_memory_for_spark_application.html) and [2](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-submit.html)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I used --executor-cores option in my spark shell as 'spark2-shell --num-executors 1 --executor-cores 1 --jars /tmp/elasticsearch-hadoop-7.1.1.jar' but still it used maximum VCores. I think it depend on Container count. i.e Container count = VCores count. Trying find solution is there any way to limit Container count. I update my question with cluster metrics picture.